# Modify makefile created using autoconf

Tags: c++, makefile, configure, autoconf, gtkmm

I am using `autoconf` to create `Makefile` for my app which is using `gtkmm-3.0`. `configure` script is running properly and makefile is generated. But the makefile puts object files after libraries as:

```
g++  -g -O2 -lgtkmm-3.0 -latkmm-1.6 -lgdkmm-3.0 -lgiomm-2.4 -lpangomm-1.4 -lgtk-3 -lglibmm-2.4 -lcairomm-1.0 -lgdk-3 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lsigc-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0    -o base base-base.o
```

which is giving following error:

```
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/papersize.h:45: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/papersize.h:45: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/papersize.h:46: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/papersize.h:46: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/papersize.h:47: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/papersize.h:47: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/papersize.h:48: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/papersize.h:48: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/papersize.h:49: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/papersize.h:49: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/papersize.h:50: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/papersize.h:50: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/papersize.h:51: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/papersize.h:51: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
base-base.o: In function `main':
/home/shashwat001/Documents/UbuntuApps/gtkmmApps/FirstApp/src/base.cpp:7: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
/home/shashwat001/Documents/UbuntuApps/gtkmmApps/FirstApp/src/base.cpp:7: undefined reference to `Gtk::Application::create(int&, char**&, Glib::ustring const&, Gio::ApplicationFlags)'
/home/shashwat001/Documents/UbuntuApps/gtkmmApps/FirstApp/src/base.cpp:7: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
/home/shashwat001/Documents/UbuntuApps/gtkmmApps/FirstApp/src/base.cpp:9: undefined reference to `Gtk::Window::Window(Gtk::WindowType)'
/home/shashwat001/Documents/UbuntuApps/gtkmmApps/FirstApp/src/base.cpp:10: undefined reference to `Gtk::Window::set_default_size(int, int)'
/home/shashwat001/Documents/UbuntuApps/gtkmmApps/FirstApp/src/base.cpp:12: undefined reference to `Gtk::Application::run(Gtk::Window&)'
/home/shashwat001/Documents/UbuntuApps/gtkmmApps/FirstApp/src/base.cpp:9: undefined reference to `Gtk::Window::~Window()'
/home/shashwat001/Documents/UbuntuApps/gtkmmApps/FirstApp/src/base.cpp:13: undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
/home/shashwat001/Documents/UbuntuApps/gtkmmApps/FirstApp/src/base.cpp:9: undefined reference to `Gtk::Window::~Window()'
```

But when I manually run the above statement with object file before libraries:

```
g++  -g -O2 -o base base-base.o -lgtkmm-3.0 -latkmm-1.6 -lgdkmm-3.0 -lgiomm-2.4 -lpangomm-1.4 -lgtk-3 -lglibmm-2.4 -lcairomm-1.0 -lgdk-3 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lsigc-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

Then no error happens. 
So the problem is order of libraries and object file. What to modify in `autoconf` script to push order change in Makefile?

Comment: My guess is that you're putting your libraries into the wrong variable.  Even though they look like options (begin with `-l`), libraries should go into the `LDLIBS` variable.  You're probably putting them into the `LDFLAGS` variable.

Comment: You are right MadScientist. That was the problem. I figured it out soon after posting it, just forgot to update it. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

> What to modify in autoconf script to push order change in Makefile?

If you use only autoconf (without automake), you need
modify files with ".in" extension, like Makefile.in,
and then rerun "./configure".

If you also use automake, instead of Makefile.in you have to edit Makefile.am.
And after that run autoreconf && ./configure